Squid proxy - make - getting errors
i am trying to install Squid proxy version 6.9 on Centos 9.
Centos 9 is installed as minimal version (including Development Tools package).
Commands that i run after installing:


sudo dnf update -y
sudo dnf groupinstall "Development Tools" -y
sudo dnf install openssl-devel libxml2-devel libcap-devel -y
sudo dnf install epel-release -y
sudo dnf --enablerepo=crb install cppunit
sudo dnf --enablerepo=crb install cppunit-devel
sudo dnf install wget tar gcc-c++ make -y


The config is used (found it on internet):

./configure --prefix=/usr --exec-prefix=${prefix} --bindir=${prefix}/bin --sbindir=${prefix}/sbin --libdir=${prefix}/lib --includedir=${prefix}/include --localstatedir=/var --libexecdir=${prefix}/lib/squid --srcdir=. --datadir=${prefix}/share/squid --sysconfdir=/etc/squid --infodir=${prefix}/share/info --mandir=${prefix}/share/man --x-includes=${prefix}/include --x-libraries=${prefix}/lib  --with-default-user=proxy --with-logdir=/var/log/squid --with-swapdir=/var/spool/squid --with-pidfile=/var/run/squid.pid --with-large-files --enable-silent-rules --enable-ssl --disable-inlined --disable-optimizations --disable-wccp --disable-wccp2 --disable-htcp --with-pthreads --with-openssl --enable-ssl-crtd --with-libnetfilter-conntrack --enable-storeio=ufs,aufs,diskd,rock --with-aufs-threads=64 --enable-linux-netfilter --enable-removal-policies=lru,heap --enable-gnuregex --enable-snmp --enable-inline --enable-htcp --enable-build-info=Ubuntu/linux --enable-x-forwarded-for --enable-x-accelerator-vary --enable-underscores --enable-http-violations --enable-async-io=64 --enable-storeid-rewrite-helpers --enable-auth-basic=DB,fake,getpwnam,NCSA,POP3,RADIUS,SMB --enable-arp --enable-arp-acl --enable-truncate --enable-stacktrace --enable-cache-digests --enable-icap-client --disable-ident-lookups --enable-delay-pools --enable-useragent-log --enable-disk-io="AIO,Blocking,DiskThreads,IpcIo,Mmapped" --disable-translation --disable-auto-locale && echo -e "CONFIGURATION SUCCESSFUL"

Make check command didnt show any error, all tests passed.
But for some reason make install doesnt install service not even dropping error.
Is there something i could check?
